# Relevance of pure mathematics vs statistics to physics

Tags: experimental-physics, education, probability, mathematics, statistics

For someone currently studying physics, with an interest in experimental physics, would pure mathematics or statistics be more relevant?

Comment: You need pure math -- calculus, linear algebra, differential equations -- for the theory; you need statistcs to evaluate experiments. As you go on you add more math, depending on the topics studied.

Comment: Statistics is an applied discipline. Do you mean stochastics? That depends. If you want to study stochastic systems in detail, a solid foundation of stochastics will will required.

Comment: @CuriousOne: Experimental physics is an applied discipline. Like all experimental sciences, it often uses statistics to extract meaningful data out of observation.

Comment: @slebetman: We are in full agreement there. My aim was more to point out that statistics and stochastics are not the same discipline, with stochastics being both more on the "pure math" side and important for certain types of physical systems, even on the experimental side.

Comment: I think that I might have worded the question a bit incorrectly; I was referring to pure math as being a separate field to topics such as linear algebra, DE's etc and was referring to subjects such as topology and group theory and comparing this to the field of statistics (analysis of data etc.).